# PHP drop down menu help needed

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu

Need help with my simple PHP menu. I'd like to have something like that: when child elements < 6 display one column if > 6 display two columns. Any advices how to make it?

Regards

Comment: Maybe will show a bit more:

When child links < X I'd like my menu to look like that:
Link
Link
Link
Link

When child links > 6:
Link Link
Link Link
Link Link
Link Link

I hope you know now what I mean

Comment: If you edit your original question, you can format your output the way you want. Also, what are you using to render the menu? i.e. do you have a JavaScript framework, are you displaying custom `<div>` elements, something else?

Comment: I added answer with code. I use jquery, just don't know how to make it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic idea, you can adapt it to work with a table:

```
if (count($childs) < 6)
{
    foreach ($childs as $child)
    { 
        echo htmlspecialchars($child)."<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    for ($n=0;$n<count($childs);$n++)
    {
        echo htmlspecialchars($child)." ";
        if ($n%2) echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

For a table:

```
if (count($childs) < 6)
{
    // Single row
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($childs as $child)
    { 
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($child)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
else
{
    // Multiple row
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($n=0;$n<count($childs);$n++)
    {
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($child)."</td>";
        if ($n%2) echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

There are other ways.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Damn, I tried to make it good way, but my code was...a bit messy :)

Answer (score 0):

If sub menu contains more than 6 links I like submenu looks like:

```
Link
Link
Link
Link
```

If more than 6 links:

```
Link Link
Link Link
Link Link
```

I'm using WP, just need advice how to make it.

Comment: Carlos, yes, WordPress blog. I built custom drop down menu, but don't know how to make it as I want :)